# Can't install SWT plugin in Eclipse 3.7.1 from any of the repositories

Tags: windows, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, windowbuilder

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.1 Indigo (Java EE IDE) on Windows 7 (32bit). I wanted to install WindowBuilder for building GUI java apps and so far I tried following repositories to install WindowBuilder or SWT plugin, but none of them completes the plugin installation and it stucks and fails in between.

WindowBuilder Pro by Google
`http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2wbpro/latest/3.7`
WindowBuilder by Eclipse `http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201109201200/3.7/`

I also tried by using fresh installation of Eclipse, but that also didn't worked, and plugin installation takes forever and in the end, it shows error "Unable to Resolve". I'm sure that my network connection is free from any firewall restrictions and is fairly fast.

I have used NetBeans so far for my Java needs, but now I need to move on Eclipse, what could be the possible solution to this problem?

Manually installing plugins would be my last option and I'd really prefer to install it using Eclipse's built-in "Install New Software".

Comment: There might be problems on update sites I experienced that sometimes with SVN plugin, try it tomorrow it will not work, please specify the error. "Unable to resolve" does not give us much info..

Answer (score 0):

Installing via this link just worked fine for me on a fresh install of Indigo.

http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/release/R201109201200/3.7/

The fact that you have the same issue from two different sites suggests it's a issue with your network, if you're still have issues try installing a completely different plugin and see if you get the same problem. Are you on a corporate network? Do you have any proxies you need to configure to allow aplications to access the net?